# CAN'T open syslog

Tags: path, syslog

I had read that syslog is placed in a /var/log directory.
But i can't open it in spite of the directory in PATH included.

```
    lm@debian:~$ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/lm/.local/bin
    lm@debian:~$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/log
    lm@debian:~$ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/lm/.local/bin:/var/log
    lm@debian:~$ sudo tail -f syslog
    tail: cannot open 'syslog' for reading: No such file or directory
    tail: no files remaining
```

how to fix this?
and does it right, that originally  the directory above doesn't included to the PATH by default?

my system is Debian 12 "bookworm"

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` variable is only used for locating executables when the shell doesn't recognise a command as an alias, shell function, or as a built-in command (simplifying it slightly).  It will not be used by the shell or by `tail` to look up arbitrary files.

If you know the file you're interested in is called `syslog` and that it's located in the `/var/log` directory, then either use `tail -f` directly on `/var/log/syslog`:

```bash
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

... or first change your working directory to `/var/log` and then look at `syslog`:

```bash
cd /var/log
tail -f syslog
```

If you change your working directory, you can switch back to the most recent working directory when you are done using

```bash
cd -
```

... or to your home directory with

```bash
cd
```

Comment: i has find, that just syslog file isn't persisted in /var/log directory. Does it must be  launched by default while the installation process or user must it launch manually?

Comment: @ant This appears to be a different question. Consider asking it separately. My answer only deals with explaining what the `PATH` variable is used for and how to access a file once you know its name and in what directory it is located.

Comment: Modern log management uses `journalctl`. Read `man journalctl`. I have `journalctl` hints in my U&L Profile,  click on my userid below.